# Set application_name during connection

Tags: javascript, postgresql, pg-promise

Is there other way to change application_name after `db.connect()` and without using `SET application_name = 'myapp'` in [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise)?

In our API the DB connection is made at the top level and is shared between many resources. We want to override the application name in various resources.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Connection Syntax](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Connection-Syntax), you can set `application_name` parameter to any string, which will do exactly what you want during the connection.